# Parse unauthorized login after migration

Tags: ios, facebook, parse-platform

I'm trying to log in through Facebook using `ParseFacebookUtilsV4` and keep getting the error: `Error Domain=Parse Code=0 "unauthorized" UserInfo={error=unauthorized, NSLocalizedDescription=unauthorized, temporary=0}`.

I just migrated to back4app from Parse and haven't changed too much code, at least as it relates to login. I've entered all my keys in back4app, and am rerouting the server using the following:

```
let configuration = ParseClientConfiguration {
     $0.applicationId = "appID"
     $0.clientKey = "clientID"
     $0.server = "https://parseapi.back4app.com"
}
Parse.initializeWithConfiguration(configuration)
```

How do I resolve this?

Comment: did you enable facebooklogin in the server config file? Or unauthorized could mean that your class has different permission set, try to set it to Public Read and you will see if you lose this error...

Comment: Yeah, I'm using back4app, and all I've done is add my FB app ID key to my back4app FB oAuth settings

Comment: hi @dperk - did you have any luck with this?

Answer (score 0):

For what I can tell there was a slight change on the initialization settings for swift and it seems to work if you do it like this:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
// Override point for customization after application launch.
let configurationOptions = ParseClientConfiguration {
    $0.applicationId = "APP_ID"
    $0.clientKey = "CLIENT_KEY"
    $0.server = "https://parseapi.back4app.com"
}
Parse.initialize(with: configurationOptions)
return true
}
```